# Need same functionality of close button from browser enabled Info path form in infopath button

Tags: infopath

In Infopath form we place a button as "close" for that we need same functionality of "Close" button behaves in browser enabled infopath form using code or script.

Scenario: After opening an Infopath form and click on close button it asks by default "Do you want to save or close" as popup, dependent on selection its working.

Needs same functionality in Close button.

Answer (score -1):

for using close button , take one button and then apply rule to that button , go to manage rule then new -> add -> click on action then choose "close form" there 
this may help you